# how to decrypt the encrypted string that using AES algorithm in java

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes

for some reason, i need to decrypt some string that were encrypted by AES algorithm(using c#) but i'm not very familiar with it, i have the source code (c# code). and i also tried using java to decrypt it, but failed.

here is the source code of c#

```
public class SymmetricEncrypt
{
    private byte[] cipherbytes;
    private byte[] finalbytes;
    private string plainTextValue;
    private static char seprate = ';';
    private SymmetricAlgorithm syma = Rijndael.Create();
    private string symmetricKeyValue = "^_^b@_@b*_*b-_-b^_^b@_@b*_*b-_-b";

    public SymmetricEncrypt()
    {
        this.Init();
    }

    public static string[] ConvertByteAryToStringAry(byte[] args)
    {
        string[] strArray = new string[args.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            strArray[i] = args[i].ToString();
        }
        return strArray;
    }

    public static byte[] ConvertStringAryToByteAry(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[args.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = Convert.ToByte(args[i]);
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    public string Decrypt(string[] args)
    {
        return this.Decrypt(ConvertStringAryToByteAry(args));
    }

    public string Decrypt(string args)
    {
        string[] strArray = args.Split(new char[] { seprate });
        return this.Decrypt(ConvertStringAryToByteAry(strArray));
    }

    public string Decrypt(byte[] args)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(args);
        CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream, this.syma.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        List<byte> list = new List<byte>();
        int num = 0;
        do
        {
            num = stream2.ReadByte();
            if (num != -1)
            {
                list.Add(Convert.ToByte(num));
            }
        }
        while (num != -1);
        this.finalbytes = list.ToArray();
        this.plainTextValue = Encoding.Default.GetString(this.finalbytes);
        return this.plainTextValue;
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt()
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream, this.syma.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(this.plainTextValue);
        stream2.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        stream2.Close();
        this.cipherbytes = stream.ToArray();
        stream.Close();
        return this.cipherbytes;
    }

    public string EncryptToString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        string[] strArray = ConvertByteAryToStringAry(this.Encrypt());
        if (strArray != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    builder.Append(strArray[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.Append(seprate.ToString()).Append(strArray[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public string[] EncryptToStringAry()
    {
        return ConvertByteAryToStringAry(this.Encrypt());
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.symmetricKeyValue);
        this.syma.Key = bytes;
        this.syma.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        this.syma.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    }

    public string PlainText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.plainTextValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                Exception exception = new Exception("明文不能为空！");
                throw exception;
            }
            this.plainTextValue = value;
        }
    }

    public string SymmetricKey
    {
        get
        {
            return this.symmetricKeyValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                Exception exception = new Exception("密钥不能为空！");
                throw exception;
            }
            if (value.Length != 0x20)
            {
                Exception exception2 = new Exception("密钥长度必须是32个字符！");
                throw exception2;
            }
            this.symmetricKeyValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the java code i tried to decrypt

```
public static String aesDecrypt(byte[] strBytes, String keyStr) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NOPadding");
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    kgen.init(128, new SecureRandom(keyStr.getBytes()));
    SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(strBytes);
    return new String(bytes, "utf-8");
}

public static byte[] convertStrArrayToByteArray(String s){
    String[] ss = s.split(";");
    byte[] bs = new byte[ss.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (String byteStr : ss) {
        bs[index ++] = (byte) (Short.parseShort(byteStr) >> 8 & 0xff);
    }
    return bs;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte b = (byte) 158;
    System.out.println(b);
    String enStr = "158;244;75;86;184;135;189;50;161;55;60;169;144;186;65;76;37;241;197;21;71;105;113;29;114;92;200;99;102;119;240;124;228;195;12;115;162;186;197;27;40;23;48;24;30;0;98;28;6;113;40;252;191;223;59;138;207;70;31;244;1;9;1;95;66;209;189;115;113;241;122;175;246;155;6;114;221;161;149;246;167;137;27;61;180;122;145;251;52;202;126;242;25;214;129;66;182;176;9;155;36;224;49;158;94;93;53;194;184;46;194;82;203;79;68;185;154;6;182;121;132;233;166;138;209;159;191;126;3;36;113;5;38;84;58;145;78;118;177;222;216;160;217;204;169;153;3;40;198;4;144;137;0;60;96;69;96;4;47;60;69;202;131;250;137;162;192;216;0;95;75;47;3;72;219;85;13;33;88;68;135;239;221;114;171;190;114;128;168;156;230;180;120;251;70;48;151;23;254;221;73;90;111;159;150;22;50;108;133;233;226;157;165;254;14;242;59;176;100;81;27;156;110;194;6;113;40;252;191;223;59;138;207;70;31;244;1;9;1;95;66;209;189;115;113;241;122;175;246;155;6;114;221;161;149;246;145;77;98;181;148;212;44;112;175;96;184;222;128;172;98;31;147;59;158;66;238;255;8;6;100;215;35;228;28;197;52;168;252;239;80;176;80;195;177;197;42;252;47;184;235;64;237;246";
    String key = "^_^b@_@b*_*b-_-b^_^b@_@b*_*b-_-b";
    System.out.println(aesDecrypt(convertStrArrayToByteArray(enStr), key));
}
```

Comment: There is a forum named like "Code Reviews" in Stack Exchange and I think this question should be putted there...

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki StackExchange-based websites aren't forums, but Q&A websites. Also, the O.P. states it doesn't work which makes it off-topic there.

Comment: Why did you initialize kgen in Java code with value from SecureRandom? You just use the UTF8 byte encoding in the C# code.

Comment: @Martheen  i do not understand the AES algorithm，how should i write the code ?

Comment: You need to be very clear on the difference between byte arrays and strings.  AES encryption produces a byte array, not a string.  Careless conversion between a byte array and a string can add or lose bytes.  I strongly suggest that you use Base64 if you need to handle byte arrays as strings.  That way nothing will be added or lost.

Answer (score 0):

i think i've solved the problem..

thanks for @Martheen's hint.

change the code as fllowed:

```
public static String aesDecrypt(byte[] strBytes, String keyStr) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NOPadding");
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    kgen.init(128, new SecureRandom(keyStr.getBytes()));
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyStr.getBytes(), "AES");

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(strBytes);
    return new String(bytes, "gb2312");
}

public static byte[] convertStrArrayToByteArray(String s){
    String[] ss = s.split(";");
    byte[] bs = new byte[ss.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (String byteStr : ss) {
        bs[index ++] = (byte) (Short.parseShort(byteStr));
    }
    return bs;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte b = (byte) 158;
    System.out.println(b);
    String enStr = "158;244;75;86;184;135;189;50;161;55;60;169;144;186;65;76;37;241;197;21;71;105;113;29;114;92;200;99;102;119;240;124;228;195;12;115;162;186;197;27;40;23;48;24;30;0;98;28;6;113;40;252;191;223;59;138;207;70;31;244;1;9;1;95;66;209;189;115;113;241;122;175;246;155;6;114;221;161;149;246;167;137;27;61;180;122;145;251;52;202;126;242;25;214;129;66;182;176;9;155;36;224;49;158;94;93;53;194;184;46;194;82;203;79;68;185;154;6;182;121;132;233;166;138;209;159;191;126;3;36;113;5;38;84;58;145;78;118;177;222;216;160;217;204;169;153;3;40;198;4;144;137;0;60;96;69;96;4;47;60;69;202;131;250;137;162;192;216;0;95;75;47;3;72;219;85;13;33;88;68;135;239;221;114;171;190;114;128;168;156;230;180;120;251;70;48;151;23;254;221;73;90;111;159;150;22;50;108;133;233;226;157;165;254;14;242;59;176;100;81;27;156;110;194;6;113;40;252;191;223;59;138;207;70;31;244;1;9;1;95;66;209;189;115;113;241;122;175;246;155;6;114;221;161;149;246;145;77;98;181;148;212;44;112;175;96;184;222;128;172;98;31;147;59;158;66;238;255;8;6;100;215;35;228;28;197;52;168;252;239;80;176;80;195;177;197;42;252;47;184;235;64;237;246";
    String key = "^_^b@_@b*_*b-_-b^_^b@_@b*_*b-_-b";
    System.out.println(aesDecrypt(convertStrArrayToByteArray(enStr), key));
}
```